# Add Multiple Header Values in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, http-headers

I know how to add one header value in Swagger, here's the code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{bookID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooksByID([FromHeader(Name = "Correlation-ID")]string bookID)
{
   //...
}
```

But what if I would like to **add additional header values**, such as "TenantID", "UserID", etc.

How would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add more parameters, and include the `FromHeader` attribute on each parameter you want to match:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{bookID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooksByID(
    string bookID,
    [FromHeader(Name = "Correlation-ID")] string correlationID,
    [FromHeader(Name = "Tenant-ID")] string tenantID,
    [FromHeader(Name = "User-ID")] string userID)
{
   //...
}
```